# How to pass the different dynamic data to different Jmeter thread?

Tags: jmeter

In my application there are three text fields as, first name, Middle name & last name,
Now i want to pass the different data to different Jmeter threads just like below,

Thread          First name       Middle name                last name

Thread1     First1           Middle1            Last1

Thread2 First2           Middle2            Last2

.           .               .
.           .               .

.           .               .

Threadn Firstn          Middlen             Lastn

I want data of first name, Middle name & last name should be in incremental order up to number of threads. please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chetan,

JMeter has some in-built functions which can be used for this purpose. Please refer to this.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

There are several ways to increment the number like this. As you want to go by the thread number, use threadNum function

```
First${__threadNum}
Middle${__threadNum}
```

So first thread will create the user as First1, Middle1 , second thread will create as First2, Middle2 and so on.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: Thanks vlns need some help, how to pass the random data to text field but not duplicate i.e. first23, first55,.....etc but not duplicate. also more info on "several ways to increment the number like this"

Comment: There is also a random function. you can combine ${__threadNum}${__Random} to pass almost unique - random data.